# Django email won't send inside a view function

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, email, django-3.1

```
def contactform(request):
if request.method == 'GET':
    form = contact_form()
else:
    form = contact_form(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        contact_name = form.cleaned_data['aname']
        contact_email = form.cleaned_data['aemail']
        contact_subject = form.cleaned_data['asubject']
        contact_message = form.cleaned_data['rmessage']
        try:
            email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
            recipient_list = ['xxx@gmail.com']
            html_message = render_to_string('main/contact.html', {'contact_email': contact_email, 'contact_name': contact_name, 'contact_message': contact_message})
            msg = EmailMessage(contact_subject, html_message, email_from, recipient_list)
            msg.content_subtype = "html"
            msg.send()
        except ValueError:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
        return render(request, "main/home.html", {'successcform': 'Success! Thank you for your message. We will reply shortly.', 'contactform': form})
return render(request, "main/home.html", {'contactform': form})
```

This works well, the email is sent when someone fills in the contact form, but if I use the send mail code with :

```
def signupuser(request):
if request.method == 'GET':
    return render(request, 'main/signupuser.html', {'form':UserCreationForm()})
else:
    if request.POST['password1'] == request.POST['password2']:
        try:
            user = User.objects.create_user(request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password1'])
            user.save()
            login(request, user)
            email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
            recipient_list = [request.POST['username']]
            contact_subject = [' ,thank you for registering to our site.']
            html_message = render_to_string('main/signupuser.html', {'username': request.POST['username']})
            msg = EmailMessage(contact_subject, html_message, email_from, recipient_list)
            msg.content_subtype = "html"
            msg.send()
            return redirect('currenttodos')
        except IntegrityError:
            return render(request, 'todo/signupuser.html', {'form':UserCreationForm(), 'error':'That username has already been taken. Please choose a new username'})
    else:
        return render(request, 'todo/signupuser.html', {'form':UserCreationForm(), 'error':'Passwords did not match'})
```

The email won't send, the user when registering doesn't receive any email. Simply doesn't work when i use it like that.
There are no errors in the console.

Comment: Should `recipient_list = [request.POST['username']]` be the email of the user and not the username?

Comment: Yes, the username is the email address.

Comment: you are sure that `request.POST['username']` is not None?

Comment: show your email setting code

Comment: `EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'xxx@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '123'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False`